# IB API - Specify order amount

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, interactive-brokers, ib-api

I am doing algo-trading using the IB Python API. When my algorithm finds a suitable trade, it queries the last ask price. With this price and the amount of money I want to invest per trade, the order size is specified. For example, if I want to invest 2,500$ and the price per share is 25$, the order size is 100.

```
order.totalQuantity = round((2500 // price), 0)
```

I sometimes have the problem that the query gives a prices of zero, especially for very small capitalized stocks even though there is a price when I look for the stock in TWS. If the price found is zero, I can't calculate an order size and my order fails.

Does someone have an idea how to solve this? For example, is there a way to specify an order quantity relative to my investment amount in a stock without using the latest ask price?

Comment: Does it keep returning zero after a retry? If not, you could ask for the price in a loop until it is different than zero

Comment: Could you show us the code you're using for the query?